# Is np.trapz linear in its function variable

Tags: python, numpy

I am given an equation `y(x') = Integral(f(x, x')*g(x), x in X)`. I'm also given a function `f` and lists of `X` values and `Y` values of length `n`. What I need is to find a list `g` of same length such that `Z[i] = np.trapz(f(X, X[i])*g, X)` satisfies `Z[i] = Y[i]`.

I have first done some analytic explorations and found how to express `g` from the original equation, but once I do this numerically I get that `Z[i] - Y[i]` is a straight line with close to zero slope, but still it introduces some consistent error.

I hence thought that maybe I need to solve for `g` directly in `np.trapz(f(X, X[i])*g, X) == Y[i]`. This should be very simple if `np.trapz` is linear in its first argument coz then it will lead to a system of linear equation on `g`. So I wonder if the linearity holds indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes, it is linear. Like the integral operator is (form f->integral_a^b f(x)dx is linear). Like any weighted sum of samples f(x₁),...,f(xₙ) is.

`trapz` is just a way to compute that integral, and is a weighted sum of some `f(xₖ)`, the xₖ being the second parameters.

You can check it experimentaly easily

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(100)
x = np.random.uniform(1,3,(100,)).cumsum()
y = np.random.uniform(-5,10,(100,))
z = np.random.uniform(-5,10,(100,))
# Is y→np.trapz(y,x) linear? If so, np.trapz(αy+βz) shoud be α×np.trapz(y)+β×np.trapz(z)
R1=5*np.trapz(y,x)-2*np.trapz(z,x)
R2=np.trapz(5*y-2*z,x)
print(f"{R1}=={R2}:", np.isclose(R1,R2))
# 1582.7905714127717==1582.7905714127721: True
```

See, same thing, to the numerical error.

Of course, that is just an experimental proof. But what are the odds of trapz not being linear, and behaving so close to a linear function for totally, not special example? Plus you can multiply those examples with different values, different seeds,... it always works.

And anyway, that is not my real answer. My real answer is the first part: the application that compute the trapezoidal approximation of an integral of a function is a linear application.
I included the experimental proof, only because this is [so], and I like answers to contain code :D

Comment: this is great, thanks. The part `any numerical integration scheme is a linear operator on the function values` together with `but let's double check this on few examples` does suffice